# How can I tune the hough transform in MATLAB to detect more lines for checkerboard detection?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to write an algorithm for detecting checkerboard patterns. I know that MATLAB has a built-in function for this but I want to do it on my own.

Anyway, I have like 30 pictures of a checkerboard pattern that are shown to the camera in different positions. I have already developed an algorithm for finding the region of interest using regionprops which is working reasonably well. However, when I apply a canny filter on the photo for detecting the edges and then finding the lines, the Hough transform fails to detect some of the lines that must be detected in few photos. See figure 1 and figure 2 for example.

Here is an MCV of my code to see my preprocessing step and my current parameters of the Hough transform:

```
img = imread('checkerboard13.jpg');
bw = im2bw(img, graythresh(img));
bw = medfilt2(bw, [9,9]);
BW = edge(bw);
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
P = houghpeaks(H, 100,'NHoodSize',[1 1],'threshold',ceil(0.01*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P, 'FillGap', 80, 'MinLength', 400);
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
figure;
    imagesc(I);hold on;colormap gray;
    axis image; 
    max_len = 0;
    for k = 1:length(lines)
       xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
       plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
       plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
       plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
       len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
       if ( len > max_len)
          max_len = len;
          xy_long = xy;
       end
    end
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using morphological operations before applying canny on your images?

Comment: @RickM.  Could you be more precise please? What kind of morphological operations do you have in mind? I have tried to remove some unimportant details by regionprops, choosing the box that has the most negative Euler number (excluding the whole picture) with some constraints on its size and its aspect ratio. That's how I have narrowed the problem to the region of interest more or less.

Comment: Looking at your canny image, I would make the lines thicker as in more continuous. You can do this by applying [dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)

Comment: @RickM. Thanks. That's a good idea. I didn't know making lines thicker was possible. I'll try it and share the result.

Comment: @RickM.  I dilated the image using imdilate in MATLAB with strel('line', 10,10). It turns out that the lines are now very bold and clear but houghtransform finds even fewer lines this time. Is this an expected behavior? What should I do? Play around with the numbers until I find a good combination or are there still other techniques that I can use?

Comment: Yes, you should play around with the dilation kernel size and the houghlines. Can you also upload one of the original images without any processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as I said in the comments, you have to play with the parameters for dilation and houghlines.

Problem: The lines that you are looking for, specifically the checker board ones, are very thin and not connected. Hence, using just Houghlines might be possible but lot of tuning of the parameters is required.

Solution: Dilate the image before applying hough lines and adjust the parameters for the hough lines accordingly.

*Dilation* is basically a morphological operation where a pixel element is '1' if atleast one pixel under the kernel is '1'. So it increases the white region in the image or size of foreground object increases. As an alternative you can also try using *Opening* which is basically erosion (opposite of dilation) + dilation.

Parameters for Houghlines:

[OpenCV function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb):

`lines =   cv.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, minLineLength[, maxLineGap]]])`

The most important parameters in your case are:

**threshold** - Decides which lines to consider, *only lines having intensities > threshold are chosen*.

**minLineLength** - As the name says, this determines what should be the minimum length of the line (in pixels) to be *categorized* as a line

**maxLineGap** - Probably the second most important parameter, if not the most important (tough competition vs the threshold), this defines what should be the *maximum gap between two lines to be categorized as one single line*.

Other parameters:

**rho**: Distance resolution in pixels, 1 here

**theta**: Angle resolution in radians, 1 here

For a good tutorial, have a look at [how hough transform works?](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm)

Using OpenCV with the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread('lines.jpg')
output = image1
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

canny = cv2.Canny(image1, 100, 200)
canny = cv2.dilate(canny, (5,5), 7)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, 1, np.pi/360, 120, minLineLength=200, maxLineGap=30)

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(output, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imwrite("lines_res.jpg", output)
```

Original image:

[image: Original]

Result:

[image: Result]

Hope it helps! Let me know what you think!

Comment: Your result is obvious a lot better than mine. But I'm afraid MATLAB might not have the same functions as OpenCV in Python. I'd appreciate it if you explained what some of those parameters in your code do. Maybe I can find an equivalent way to implement it in MATLAB. Also, another issue is that my code should work on 30 pictures that are very different from each other. So, maybe playing around with the parameters gives good result on this one, but fails on the other ones.

Comment: Thats a fair point. I will explain why I use such parameters in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But what does 1, np.pi/360 and 120 do? I mean what parameters are they?

Comment: added to the edit.For the case where all the images are different, I can't help you until I have looked at those images but if the distance from the camera for the images is same and they aren't blurry (I can go on with this) they should be fine. Hopefully you can find similar parameters in the matlab implementation and are less _stressed out_ (wink).

Comment: It seems that HoughLinesP is a probabilistic version of the Hough transform and MATLAB doesn't have it yet. I checked rho and theta in the classical Hough transform. They must be vectors. Rho is 1 &times; 2415 and theta is 1 &times; 180 in our example. But in your case they're just simple scalar numbers. :(

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found a solution to solve it on MATLAB.

Comment: Let me see what I can do

Comment: Thanks. That's nice of you.